# Execute a shell script in another unix machine using SSH

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I am trying to execute a script which is present in another unix machine from my unix box using below command:

```
HOST=myhostname
USER=myuser

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l $USER $HOST "/tmp/myscript.sh"
```

But the command prompts me to enter the password, but I don't want the command to prompt for password, instead of that I want to pass the password as parameter for my command. But I am not able to find an option to pass the password as parameter to `SSH` command.

Please help me on how to send password as part of command, instead of the command to prompt it. I am using BASH shell script.

Comment: Sending the password would not be secure. Have a look at `ssh-keygen` as an alternative.

Comment: [ssh without a password](http://csua.berkeley.edu/~ranga/notes/ssh_nopass.html)

Answer (score 0):

## Use EXPECT

Save this as mylogin.exp (or some other name you like), and change the names and password:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh myname@some_server.com
expect {
   password:   {send "mypassword\n"}
}
interact
```

Then just run the command:

```
./mylogin.exp
```

That will just get you logged in.  If you want to run a command instead, you can just put that at the end of the ssh command.